# App store automatically says need 5.1 and higher for my app

Tags: ios, app-store

I don't remember specifying anywhere that I will only support iOS 5.1 and higher in my project settings. I only have my iOS deployment target set to 5.0. My app recently started saying the device needs to have 5.1 and higher. I would like to support 5.0 though. 
Let me know if there is any issue with the new update that I don't know about. Or if I inadvertently changed something that set this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, click your project on the top of the menu on the left, with the blueprint icon. Under 'Info', the first thing should be 'iOS Deployment Target'. Just change that. It will take effect next time you submit an update to the store.

Comment: As I said, its already set to 5.0 Why wasn't it accounted for in the first place?